# failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage

Tags: docker-registry, docker-for-windows, docker

I have a private docker registry on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter and from local machine (Windows 10 Pro) I pushed few images to it. When I try to pull image from server it starts pulling and later throws an error

**failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage \?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\f9613d03a4fae39c0cebca07bc51aef2931756f5e674cda8f6b78729ba5ebac8\UtilityVM: The system cannot find the path specified.**

I used following image and steps to start a registry https://hub.docker.com/r/stefanscherer/registry-windows/

I tested with hello-world image, pushed it from local machine and pulled it from server, it worked.

But, I am unable pull images like microsoft/wcf, microsoft/iis which are base images to my local built images.

Other way around, if I already have microsoft/wcf image on my server (which is base image for my locally built image), when pulling the locally built image why it goes to pull microsoft/wcf again. Is there any way I can use server's wcf image?

**docker verion**

Client:
 Version:       17.06.2-ee-13
 API version:   1.30
 Go version:    go1.8.7
 Git commit:    ac44d73
 Built: Mon Jun  4 16:46:59 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.06.2-ee-13
  API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:   go1.8.7
  Git commit:   ac44d73
  Built:        Mon Jun  4 16:58:47 2018
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
  Experimental: true

Comment: You are right! That's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following links are helpful to resolve this issue:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2119

[Can't pull image from docker, ProcessUtilityVMImage cannot find the path specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907911/cant-pull-image-from-docker-processutilityvmimage-cannot-find-the-path-specifi)