# Can't pull image from docker, ProcessUtilityVMImage cannot find the path specified

Tags: docker

I have made a .net core app and it is uploaded to docker hub

When I try to pull it to my own machine, (win 10) it just works

When I try to pull it to the server (server 2016) I get an error:

```
docker pull arrivaflg/flg:20180618104928

....

failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\cf1f49a6508aaa657768d667c58779e571392a80be0ba7519fe0835ac2476402\UtilityVM: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

But the really interesting part is when I try to pull a specific microsoft image, I get the SAME error message. (this is the version 1709 visual studio uses in the docker file on my machine)

```
c:\tmp>docker pull microsoft/nanoserver:1709
1709: Pulling from microsoft/nanoserver
407ada6e90de: Extracting [==================================================>]  81.04MB/81.04MB
85710d780d68: Download complete
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\cf1f49a6508aaa657768d667c58779e571392a80be0ba7519fe0835ac2476402\UtilityVM: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

If I don't specify the version number (and it just defaults to latest) there is no problem with getting the nano server on the server

But still a problem with getting mine image to the server.

So I'm guessing I should use a specific version of the nano server.

I have tried with these in my dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS base
and
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1803 AS base
```

My server information:

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker info
Containers: 3
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 3
Server Version: 17.06.2-ee-11
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.2312.amd64fre.rs1_release.180607-1919)
Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 4GiB
Name: AWS1twAROS001
ID: IVVQ:GK2Q:DNJ7:PW6W:GYZ7:WYQM:65VV:Q4JM:6BEL:5CGQ:ISXY:AWEF
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error message typically indicates that the host system is running an older kernel version than that of the Docker image. As you can see in the table on the [Windows Container Version Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility) page, Windows Server 2016 doesn't support containers based on Windows Server version 1709 or Windows Server version 1803. However, Windows 10 version 1803 **does** support them through Hyper-V isolation mode, which is why the images were able to work correctly on your own machine.

Your attempts at using different base image versions are almost correct, you simply need the right tag for Windows Server 2016, as listed under the **"Windows Server 2016 amd64 tags"** section of the [`aspnetcore` image page on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/):

`FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-sac2016 AS base`

This will use the build of the ASP.NET Core image that was built against the Windows Server 2016 version of the Nano Server image, which can then be used under a Windows Server 2016 host system.